# TestNG Emailable Report 0kb

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, testng

I'm trying to use TestNG EmailableReporter2 in my tests but the generated html file is 0kb and does not contain any tests.

I've added

```
<listeners>        
    <listener class-name="org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2" />
</listeners>
```

To my testng.xml, the report file is generating without issues, but does not contain any data.

I have a few hunches, because before this was working fine for me. Could this be because something's wrong with my pom.xml? (Previously I haven't used maven in my automation projects)

Not likely, but could this be because of some proxy issues?

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>package.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtID</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>                
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.8.1</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>log4j</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.2.17</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question was answered in the issue https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1412

> You have not specified the testng.xml location to maven.
>
> Check:
>   https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html
>
> Feel free to reopen the issue if it doesn't work and if you think it
>   is a testng issue.

Comment: Hi Krishnan, yes, I was the one who raised that issue on github. But even after editing the pom.xml I still get the same results. I have tried specifying relative path to testng.xml in the pom file, as well as full path, tried moving testng.xml file to a different location but nothing got me the desired result. Do you know what might be the issue?